# Unable to click button on Mobile App in android

Tags: android, selenium, appium-android

I am new of mobile app automation tested using Appium with TestNG.Am practicing to automate amazon app, App was launching successfully but when I try to click login option, it's getting:

> "FAILED: login org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An
>   element could not be located on the page using the given search
>   parameters. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information) Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds"

```
    public void login() throws InterruptedException{

        System.out.println("Login check");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
//      String sample = driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@class='android.widget.Button' and @index='5']").getText();
        System.out.println("Next sleep");

//      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@class='android.widget.Button' and @index='5']')]")).click();
//      driver.findElement(By.id("in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping:id/sign_in_button")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@index='5']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println("Pass");

    }
```

Image:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"//android.widget.Button[@index='5']"` is **invalid** xpath locator. If you will ever what to use index (but I strongly suggest not to do it), do it this way:

`"(//android.widget.Button)[5]"`

But in your case the best is to search by resource-id:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("sign_in_button")).click();
```

And if it still doesn't work you can print app screen xml structure just before you search for element:

`System.out.println(driver.getPageSource())`

Analyse the xml you get if it contains your button and what are the attributes of it.

Comment: So far have tried all the way, even u suggest way also. but no luck to proceed further. please find below my code and let me know once.

Comment: // driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@class='android.widget.Button' and @index='5']')]")).click();
  // driver.findElement(By.id("in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping:id/sign_in_button")).click();
   //driver.switchTo().frame(5);
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//android.widget.Button)[5]")).click();
//   driver.findElement(By.id("sign_in_button")).click();

Comment: in such case I suggest to call `driver.getPageSource()` and print it out (e.g. `System.out.println`) right before you I searching for a button. Check the xml you get if there is a button and what attributes you can you to search for it. Btw, what appium server version/ java client version you are using? If not 1.7.1/5.0.4 then update and try again

Comment: Yes, It's working after updating Java Client (5.0.4) Jar file. Thanks for your valuable help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
MobileElement el1 = (MobileElement) driver.findElementById("in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping:id/sign_in_button");

el1.click();
```